# Как правильно сочетаются сноски со знаками препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добавил еще 3 примера. Вариант "Б" отличается от остальных тем, что сноска относится только к слову "иностранец", а возглас "О!" - по-русски звучит так же, как по-испански.

Сноска относится к фразе, выделенной курсивом.

[image: Добавил еще 3 примера. Вариант "Б" отличается от остальных тем, что сноска относится только к слову "иностранец", а возглас "О!" - по-русски звучит так же, как по-испански.]

Comment: Виктор, вы знаете, чем больше я пытаюсь понять, зачем вам все это надо - тем меньше понимаю. Вы точно уверены, что бразильцы говорят по-испански? А точки тогда что у вас значат? Это опущенный текст, а в рукописи у вас там слова стоят? По сути я ответ я свой дал, менять мне там нечего.

Comment: @begemot Бразильский экскурсовод говорил по английски - язык международного общения должен знать представитель этой профессии, в какой бы стране он не жил. (Хотя мне попадались "экземпляры"...) Выбрал для примеров короткие фразы, которые привожу (А, Б, В) полностью. В жизни - ответы латиноамериканцев  были длиннее, я сократил их.

Comment: Виктор, в трёх новых примерах Вы оформили фразы как прямую речь. Она объясняет кавычки, но не объясняет отточий (многовато). Мильчин советует в случае непременной нуждаемости сноски перед знаком ставить звёздочку (если поясняется одно конкретное слово). А иначе - *"Оу! Экстраньеро?"1 - удивилась женщина.* В общем, везде убрать "романтические" точки и ставить сноску за закрывающей прямую речь кавычкой.

Comment: "Геликоптер"1, - ответил бразилец. "В двух километрах"1, - ответили мне. "О! Иностранец!"1 - удивилась женщина.

Comment: Ладно, удаляю многоточия...

Answer (score 3):

И очень даже просто - подглядываем в Розенталя:

[**§ 138. Последовательность знаков при сноске**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm)

> 1. **Запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие** и **точка** ставятся **после знака сноски**, чтобы показать, что **сноска относится к слову или группе слов**, например (многоточием здесь обозначен текст):
>
> …<sup>1</sup>, …<sup>1</sup>; …<sup>1</sup>: …<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 2. **Вопросительный** или **восклицательный знак**, **многоточие** и **кавычки** ставятся **перед знаком сноски**, чтобы показать, что сноска относится ко всему предложению, например:
>
> …?<sup>1</sup> …!<sup>1</sup> (…) …<sup>1</sup> …»<sup>1</sup>

Есть хороший сайт, раскладывающий великое учение Дитмара Эльяшевича по полочкам:

[**§ 160. При оформлении сносок соблюдается следующая последовательность знаков:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=482)

> **1.** Если сноска относится к слову или группе слов внутри предложения, то **запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, тире** ставятся
>   **после знака сноски**:
>
> *текст<sup>1</sup>, текст<sup>1</sup>; текст<sup>1</sup>: текст<sup>1</sup> —*
>
> **2.** Если есть знаки **вопросительный, восклицательный** и **многоточие**, относящиеся ко всему предложению, то они ставятся **перед знаком сноски**:
>
> *текст?<sup>1</sup> текст!<sup>1</sup> текст...<sup>1</sup>.*
>
> **3.** Если сноска относится ко всему предложению и в конце его отсутствуют знаки, указанные в п. 2, то после знака сноски ставится
>   точка:
>
> *текст<sup>1</sup>.*
>
> **4.** Кавычки ставятся перед знаком сноски:
>
> *текст»<sup>1</sup>.*
>
> **5.** Сноска, относящаяся к слову или группе слов, заключенных в скобки, ставится перед закрывающей скобкой: *(текст<sup>1</sup>);* сноска,
>   относящаяся ко всему предложению, имеющему конечную вставку, ставится
>   после скобки: *(текст)<sup>1</sup>.*
>
> ---

В Ваших примерах:

1. Геликоптер, - непонятно, что у Вас делают кавычки;

   - если сноска относится к геликоптеру, то за ним и ставится,
   - если к некоему романтизированному многоточием названию "Геликоптер...", то за кавычками.
2. Рroximo destino, - если закавычено, то после кавычек.
3. N.B.! ***"...Сноска относится к слову или группе слов"*** - наш случай: по-любому точка за сноской, даже если Вы хотите спеть оду одному лишь мирадору.

> Мирадор (исп. mirador [’mɪrədɔ:r] — 1. бельведер; 2. башенка):
>
> Мирадор (порт. Mirador) — муниципалитет в Бразилии, входит в штат
>   Парана. Составная часть мезорегиона Северо-запад штата Парана. Входит
>   в экономико-статистический микрорегион Паранаваи.
>
> Мирадор (порт. Mirador) — муниципалитет в Бразилии, входит в штат
>   Мараньян. Составная часть мезорегиона Восток штата Мараньян. Входит в
>   экономико-статистический микрорегион Шападас-ду-Алту-Итапекуру.

Исключение по [Мильчину](http://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/28846.html):

> **Знак сноски в сочетании с точкой как знаком сокращения**
>
> Знак точки ставят после точки как знака сокращения и опускают точку
>   как знак препинания в конце предложения.
>
> [...это произошло] в 1922 г.<sup>1</sup>

Comment: *по-любому сноска за точкой, даже если Вы хотите спеть оду одному лишь мирадору.* - а вот это просто неверно. Тем более, что ни о чем подобном в тексте цитат не говориться.

Comment: @Galina «Мирадорами» в Латинской Америке называют смотровые площадки в горах. Обычно к ним ведет протоптанная дорожка, иногда над обрывом присутствует ограждение. Но, если забраться на гору, где никто еще не бывал, с вершины которой открывается панорамный вид на долину, – это тоже будет Mirador.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял, речь не о ссылках, а о сносках.

Здесь нет возможности удобно набирать надстрочные индексы, поэтому в примерах будет в сточку.

В первом случае знак сноски ставится сразу после слова.

> «Helicopter(1) …»
>
> //----
>   (1) - вертолет

Во втором - в зависимости от того, к чему ссылка относится.
Если к последнему слову, то внутри кавычек.

> «proximo destino(2)»
>   //----
>
> (2) ....

Если ко всему обороту, то после

> «proximo destino»(3)
>   //----
>
> (3)....

//----

Ну вот с рисунком можно считать, что я угадал.
В принципе все варианты возможны (хотя 2) - маловероятен.

Случаи 1 и 3 означают, что сноска относится к последнему слову (или нескольким словам), 2 и 4 - ко всему обороту, заключенному в кавычки.

> Сноска относится ко всей фразе, поэтому, в отличие от остального
>   текста, она выделена курсивом.

Тогда - 2 и 4. Но очень смущает отточие в конструкции, которую надо пояснять сноской.

(+) 
6 - невозможно.

Comment: Т.е. все варианты приемлемы, кроме шестого? А правило, какое-то есть, или поверить вам на слово?

Comment: Придется поверить, если никто не разжует, я не берусь. Понимаете, это не относится к правилам русского языка, это соглашения при верстке. А на них нет общепринятых авторитетных источников. Ну приняли - и приняли так. Да, возможны все варианты, кроме шестого. Но выбор зависит от ситуации, а не от воли редактора или автора.